# dolphin create service menu for all files

Tags: 14.04, dolphin, mime-type

I want to create my own service menu entry in dolphin, that will appear for all file/directory types. Which mime type would be necessary for that?

Also: where do I find the available mime-types, that are inputable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the mime type would be

```
MimeType=all/all
```

An overview over all files can be found under

```
/usr/share/mime/
```

As you can see, its always in the form of XXX/YYY. XXX stands for of the folders inside /usr/share/mime and YYY should be a name of the files inside that folder (without the extension).

Answer (score 0):

From the [official documentation](https://develop.kde.org/docs/apps/dolphin/service-menus/)

> To create a servicemenu for all files, use the base `application/octet-stream` mimetype